# Powershell read property file multiple level of depth

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I found this [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/186030/how-to-use-a-config-file-ini-conf-with-a-powershell-script) on serverfault.se to read properties into a `HashTable`:

```
$ini = @{}
switch -regex -file "properties.ini"
{

    "^\[(.+)\]$" {
        $section = $matches[1]
        $ini[$section] = @{}
    }
    "(.+)=(.+)" {
        $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
    }
}
```

This works fine for property files like this:

```
[vendor]
vendor1=porsche
[engine]
engine1=f1.engine
```

These properties can then be accessed with:

```
$ini.vendor.vendor1
$ini.engine.engine1
```

The issue I have with this is, that I would like to add a "new level of depth" to it. I have adjusted the property file like this:

```
[vendor]
vendor1=porsche
[engine]
carengine.f1=f1-engine
carengine.dmt=dmt-engine
```

Now I would expect to access the properties with

$ini.engine.carengine.f1

which then should output `f1-engine`. Yet this doesn't work as expected. I guess that is because of the way the way a hashtable is accessed.

Actually I just found a way to access the properties with the current version:

```
$ini.engine."carengine.f1"
```

Though this requires `"` to work.

The question is, what needs to change to add a new level of depth that can be accessed without enclosing it in `"`?

Comment: You need to add a new switch case for the new level. At the moment this case "(.+)=(.+)" matches and that's the reason why you only can access the value with "carengine.f1".

Comment: So I would need to add a new switch case for every new level I want to add? So `$ini.engine.carengine.f1.motor.tiny.part` would require a total of 6 switch cases?

Comment: I'm not a regex expert but as I understood your code: Yes. Because there is the assignmend `$name,$value = $matches[1..2]`. So you need every case to do the proper assignment.

Comment: The INI file format doesn't support what you're trying to express. `carengine.dmt=dmt-engine` is a key "carengine.dmt" (the dot being part of the key name) with a value "dmt-engine", not a key "carengine" with a nested hash with another "dmt" and a value "dmt-engine". Consider using a different format, e.g. JSON.